# get youtube videos listed in subsection of channel's 'videos'

Tags: youtube-data-api

How can I get videos listed in an item of the dropdown menu of a channel's 'videos' tab?

[image]

Is it a playlist with an ID? If I wanted to get all the uploaded videos, I could first query the id of playlist 'uploads' (here for channel `UCj7IJ427cnavyq2ZOpSKYfA`):

`GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=UCj7IJ427cnavyq2ZOpSKYfA&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1`

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  ...,
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      ...,
      "contentDetails": {
        "relatedPlaylists": {
          "likes": "",
          "favorites": "",
          "uploads": "UUj7IJ427cnavyq2ZOpSKYfA" # <- here it is!
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and use it to run `playlistItems`. But what about that 'Upcoming livestreams' part only?

Answer (score -1):

You should use the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint, invoked with the request parameters `channelId`, `type` and `eventType` set accordingly:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${API_KEY}&type=video&eventType=upcoming&part=snippet&maxResults=50&channelId=${CHANNEL_ID}`,

where `${CHANNEL_ID}` is the ID the the channel of your interest and `${API_KEY}` is your API key.

For the channel you mentioned above -- that with ID `UCj7IJ427cnavyq2ZOpSKYfA` --, the JSON response looked like:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "...",
  "regionCode": "...",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 4,
    "resultsPerPage": 4
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "quPJtDE4C_PAgFJU9QIjA5d_C4k",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "JksecRTzbgo"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-05-19T10:33:39Z",
        "channelId": "UCj7IJ427cnavyq2ZOpSKYfA",
        "title": "LIVE: Т. Владимиров, фортепиано. Бах, Рахманинов, Шуберт",
        "description": "Тимофей ВЛАДИМИРОВ, фортепиано В программе: И.С. Бах. Шестиголосный ричеркар из цикла «Музыкальное приношение» Рамо – Годовский.",
        "thumbnails": {
           ...
        },
        "channelTitle": "MOSCOW INTERNATIONAL PERFORMING ARTS CENTER",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming",
        "publishTime": "2021-05-19T10:33:39Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "7LTWdzCS0NDFayU3zbfDcb3xky4",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "G85Prxi4Mr0"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-05-25T12:28:10Z",
        "channelId": "UCj7IJ427cnavyq2ZOpSKYfA",
        "title": "LIVE: Лауреаты IV Конкурса пианистов В. Крайнева в возрастной категории от 16 до 22 лет",
        "description": "В День защиты детей Концерт победителей и лауреатов IV Международного конкурса пианистов Владимира Крайнева в возрастной категории от 16 ...",
        "thumbnails": {
           ...
        },
        "channelTitle": "MOSCOW INTERNATIONAL PERFORMING ARTS CENTER",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming",
        "publishTime": "2021-05-25T12:28:10Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "I4FOz2ykBQviPr_7vdF87240iG8",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "tKDEjh37BrA"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-05-25T12:01:48Z",
        "channelId": "UCj7IJ427cnavyq2ZOpSKYfA",
        "title": "LIVE: Лауреаты IV Конкурса пианистов В. Крайнева в возрастной категории от 7 до 12 лет",
        "description": "В День защиты детей Концерт победителей и лауреатов IV Международного конкурса пианистов Владимира Крайнева в возрастной категории от 7 до ...",
        "thumbnails": {
           ...
        },
        "channelTitle": "MOSCOW INTERNATIONAL PERFORMING ARTS CENTER",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming",
        "publishTime": "2021-05-25T12:01:48Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "tpF_wpRF43W6fv1MGpNnCBSvCDU",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "R9Em6BJW0e0"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-05-25T12:08:55Z",
        "channelId": "UCj7IJ427cnavyq2ZOpSKYfA",
        "title": "LIVE: Лауреаты IV Конкурса пианистов В. Крайнева в возрастной категории от 13 до 15 лет",
        "description": "В День защиты детей Концерт победителей и лауреатов IV Международного конкурса пианистов Владимира Крайнева в возрастной категории от 13 ...",
        "thumbnails": {
           ...
        },
        "channelTitle": "MOSCOW INTERNATIONAL PERFORMING ARTS CENTER",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming",
        "publishTime": "2021-05-25T12:08:55Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Do note that the `Search.list` endpoint is relatively expensive: each call of it will cost you 100 units of quota (accounted from your daily quota, which by default is 10000 units).

Comment: i am familiar with search, of course, but i specifically want videos in some named part of 'videos' tab. only those, nothing else.

Comment: @Igor Pozdeev: So you're not interested by *Upcoming live streams*, as per your screenshot and question text above?

Comment: It could be named something else, i guess. The q is not how to get upcoming livestreams, but how to get videos listed in an item of a drop-down menu @stvar

Comment: Sorry, @Igor Pozdeev, but I don't understand you. `Search.list` queried with `eventType=upcoming` (along with `type=video` and `channelId=...`) returns the IDs of the videos that are *upcoming live streams* on the specified channel. Isn't this what you want to have: the IDs of the videos that *are going to be live* in the near future on the respective channel? Do you want to achieve something else?

Comment: Furthermore, @Igor Pozdeev, the `PlaylistItems.list` endpoint has only two current use cases: (1) you give it a user-defined playlist ID, for to obtain that user-defined playlist's content; (2) you give to the endpoint the *uploads playlist ID* of a channel, for to list almost all (max. 20000) uploaded videos of the respective channel. That's all there is. There's no other magic/special/documented *kind of playlist IDs*, that will allow one to query `PlaylistItems.list` with.

Comment: Specifically, @Igor Pozdeev, there's no auto-generated playlist (from the perspective of YouTube Data API) that will contain the *upcoming live streams* of a given channel. The method I described above is the only documented way of querying the API for the set of IDs of videos that are *upcoming live streams* of a given channel.

Comment: thanks for your input! forget about livestreams for a sec. if you go to a channel's 'videos' tab, you can see a drop-down menu with 'all videos', 'uploads', 'livestreams' etc. 'uploads' is actually a playlist which you can query as i describe in my question, and this is a cheaper (quota cost of 1) way to get a list of videos in a channel. i wonder if other dropdown menu items are playlists and how i can pull videos from them. cheers!

Comment: No, @Igor Pozdeev, as I said above, for the point of view of YouTube Data API (as opposed to the point of view of YouTube's website), there exists no other auto-generated playlists (as opposed to the user-defined ones), excluding the special case of the auto-generated uploads playlists.